# Javascript form validation not working

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I can't understand why my javascript isn't working... Do i need to declare a variable somewhere?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function validation(form) {        
if(form.first_name.value == '' ) {  alert('Please enter your first name');      form.first_name.focus(); return false; } 

if(form.00N30000006S4uq.value == '') {  alert('Please enter the high end of your budget');   form.company.focus(); return false; } 

return true; }
</script>



<form action="https://www.salesforce.com/servlet/servlet.WebToLead" method="POST" onsubmit="return validation(this);">
```

Comment: And what about the rest of the form, can we see the markup please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by @ReturnTrue, the **NAME** must begin with a letter. That is why your script is failing.

In your case since the field is auto-generated, if you know the flow of the elements in the form then you can reference the form elements array, like this...

```
form.elements[2].value
```

where `form.elements[2]` is `form.00N30000006S4uq`. That will do the job.

**Example:**

```
function validation(form) {
  if(form.elements[0].value == '' ) {
      alert('Please enter your first name');
      form.first_name.focus();
      return false;
  }

  if(form.elements[2].value == '') {
      alert('Please enter the high end of your budget');
      form.company.focus();
      return false;
  }

  return true;
}

<form action="" method="POST" onSubmit="return validation(this);">
<input type="text" name="first_name" />
<input type="text" name="company" />
<input type="text" name="00N30000006S4uq" />
<input type="submit" name="submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: Let me know how it goes and dont forget to accept the answer if you are happy with it.

Comment: so ... `if(form.elements[2].value` selects each form element in order? 12345... and so on?

Comment: Yes. That's correct. Remember the first element is 0 - `elements[0]`  and so on.

Comment: okay the live version is at [link](http://fish.cutewhitecloud.com/formtest.php)
still not quite working.. but ill play with it and then hopefully i can accept your answer!

Comment: that and the javascript is giving me the alert box, but still sending them to the thank you page.. I'm pretty sure how to handle that but if you have any simple ideas it'd be nice. :)

Comment: You are doing `form.company.focus()` while there is no field called `company` in your form. Remove that line and it will not go to the thank you page.

Answer (score 1):

Form names need to begin with a letter. "00N30000006S4uq" fails because it begins with a number.

See: http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/types.html#type-cdata

Comment: that was auto-generated by salesforce.com :/ can i use a variable?